# Unable to deploy basic android app

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I just started trying to develop a simple hello world android app. Since I am using an AMD processor the default emulator that comes with Android Studio isn't working so I have setup genymotion emulator.

I did a new project with just hello world written in it. But when I try to deploy it in the emulator I am getting the following error

```
Unexpected error: package manager reports that package in.techbreeze.android.hello has not been installed: Expected string 'Package [in.techbreeze.android.hello]' not found in output: Can't find service: package
```

Detail error message reads:

```
Unexpected error: package manager reports that package in.techbreeze.android.hello has not been installed: Expected string 'Package [in.techbreeze.android.hello]' not found in output: Can't find service: package

java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:113)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.InstalledApks.setInstalled(InstalledApks.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.uploadAndInstallApk(AndroidRunningState.java:1205)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.doPrepareAndStart(AndroidRunningState.java:920)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.prepareAndStartApp(AndroidRunningState.java:874)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.prepareAndStartAppWhenDeviceIsOnline(AndroidRunningState.java:842)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.doStart(AndroidRunningState.java:676)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.start(AndroidRunningState.java:652)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState$1.run(AndroidRunningState.java:298)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
```

What is the probable cause of this error? Is some configuration missing from my end?

Comment: You may check here:https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79778 and update your IDE to latest one

Comment: It's _much_ easier if you run HelloWorld on a real device. Once that's up and running und you know that your build process basically works switch to an emulator (if you want to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may :

Update your IDE to latest one (such as Android studio 1.0.1)

Change your `build.gradle` to something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hellomap"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
}
```

Make sure you have latest `buildToolsVersion` such that `21.1.1`