# Unable to run Libgdx game on android device

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I just made a game with LibGdx and was trying to run it on the android device, however, I got a error like the following below. I read some article about a similar issue on stackoverflow, however, it did not help me.

If there are some developers out here who knows about the issue, It would be a great if you can give me a helping hand. I would love to hear from you !

```
19:05:29 Throwable: Unexpected error: package manager reports that package com.mygame.android has not been installed: Expected string 'Package [com.mygame.android]' not found in output: 
19:05:36 Gradle build finished in 1 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which article you saw, but here's one which has an accepted answer from the original poster. So give these things a try if you haven't already.
[Unable to deploy basic android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535188/unable-to-deploy-basic-android-app)

Also, have you tried testing the default libgdx project (that displays the badlogic logo image) on your android device? Does this run ok or does this also not work?

Comment: I simply followed this tutorial ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzBVTPaUUDg  ) , Just like the video, I just made the project with the android studio, however , the app crashes when running on the real device.